# MoveIt, no acceleration limit was defined

Tags: ros2, rviz, moveit, launch-file

I created my own robot model in URDF and used the MoveIt Setup Assistant to create the MoveIt configuration and launch file. Planning and executing a motion with Rviz works except when using a Cartesian path. Planning a Cartesian path in Rviz works but I cannot execute it and shows the following error:

```
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1692688601.194486388] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.cartersian_path_service_capability]: Attempting to follow 1 waypoints for link 'lower_end_effector_link' using a step of 0.010000 m and jump threshold 0.000000 (in global reference frame)
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1692688601.210301262] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.cartersian_path_service_capability]: Computed Cartesian path with 108 points (followed 100.000000% of requested trajectory)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1692688601.210648935] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame_planning]: Achieved 100.000000 % of Cartesian path
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1692688601.453862996] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: No acceleration limit was defined for joint lower_arm_joint! You have to define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1692688601.453887546] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame_planning]: Computing time stamps FAILED
```

The content of my joint_limits file:

```
joint_limits:
  lower_arm_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 1.0
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 10.0
  lower_end_effector_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 1.0
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 10.0
  upper_arm_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 1.0
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 10.0
  upper_end_effector_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 1.0
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 10.0
  vertical_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 1.0
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 10.0
```

I also see the following line in the logs: `Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.` Does this mean that the limits in the joint_limits.yaml file are not used? Does anyone know how to solve the limits error?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Firstly, `Using load_yaml() ...` is a warning. Thus it can be ignored. Next, the following links could be helpful for the error related to acceleration limits: [1](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/2155), and [2](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/2198).

Comment: @ravi Thank you and thank you for the links. I currently use the generated `demo.launch.py` file from the MoveIt Setup Assistant. I will try and create my own launch file based on the panda launch file and see if that works.